# SQLite Affinity Bug?

Tags: sqlite

EDIT:
The answer here: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) assists in understanding this question. However, this question is not language agnostic. It is specific to the documented behavior and affinity of floating point numbers as handled by SQLite. Having a very similar answer to a different question != duplicate question.

QUESTION:
I have a rather complex SQLite Where Clause comparing numerical values. I have read and "think" I understand the Datatype Documentation here: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Still confused as to the logic SQLite uses to determine datatypes in comparison clauses such as =, >, <, <> etc. I can narrow my example down to this bit of test SQL of which the results make little sense to me.

```
SELECT
    CAST(10 AS NUMERIC) + CAST(254.53 AS NUMERIC) = CAST(264.53 AS NUMERIC) AS TestComparison1,

    CAST(10 AS NUMERIC) + CAST(254.54 AS NUMERIC) = CAST(264.54 AS NUMERIC) AS TestComparison2

Result: "1" "0"
```

The second expression in the select statement (TestComparison2) is converting the left-side of the equation to a TEXT value. I can prove this by casting the right-side of the equation to TEXT and the result = 1.

Obviously I'm missing something in the way SQLite computes Affinity. These are values coming from columns in a large/complex query. Should I be casting both sides of the equations in WHERE/Join Clauses to TEXT to avoid these issues?

Comment: How are you issuing that query? Both of those expressions have a `typeof()` integer.

Comment: @DanD. I am executing the query using the latest version of SQLite DB Browser for SQLite 3.10.1 in my test enviroment and using the latest binaries for the latest version of SQLite3.dll in a .net console app (both the same results). I understand from reading the documentation they should be integer. If that is the case, then maybe this is a rounding bug.

Comment: @DanD. FYI - only reason i'm doing a CAST of Numeric in my test example is because the columns these come from are Numeric. I know that means nothing to SQLite (it will determine the datatype on the fly using the affinity rules). However, at this point I suspect a bug and am using this as an example that closely simulates my table setup and successfully reproducing what I believe is a bug. However, you can remove all of the casting and it seems to make no difference - issue still presents itself.

Comment: It is floating point: 10 + 254.53 is 264.53 but 10 + 254.54 is 264.53999999999996.

Comment: @DanD.
Ah... you're right! It is using float as soon as you apply the + operator. This seems to contradict the documentation which states "Any operators applied to column names, including the no-op unary "+" operator, convert the column name into an expression which always has no affinity." Am I just misunderstanding what that statement really means? Thanks for your explanation! I believe in this case, round() functions will solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting the expected result is that the underlying results will be floating point.

Although [DataTypes in SQLite3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) covers much, you should also consider the following section from **[Expressions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)** :-

> **Affinity of type-name   Conversion Processing**
>
> #### NONE
>
> Casting a value to a type-name with no affinity causes the value to be converted into a BLOB. Casting to a BLOB consists of first
>   casting the value to TEXT in the encoding of the database connection,
>   then interpreting the resulting byte sequence as a BLOB instead of as
>   TEXT.
>
> #### TEXT
>
> To cast a BLOB value to TEXT, the sequence of bytes that make up the BLOB is interpreted as text encoded using the database
>   encoding.
>
> Casting an INTEGER or REAL value into TEXT renders the value as if via
>   sqlite3_snprintf() except that the resulting TEXT uses the encoding of
>   the database connection.
>
> #### REAL
>
> When casting a BLOB value to a REAL, the value is first converted to TEXT.
>
> When casting a TEXT value to REAL, the longest possible prefix of the
>   value that can be interpreted as a real number is extracted from the
>   TEXT value and the remainder ignored. Any leading spaces in the TEXT
>   value are ignored when converging from TEXT to REAL.
>
> If there is no prefix that can be interpreted as a real number, the
>   result of the conversion is 0.0.
>
> #### INTEGER
>
> When casting a BLOB value to INTEGER, the value is first converted to TEXT.
>   When casting a TEXT value to INTEGER, the longest possible prefix of the value >that can be interpreted as an integer number is extracted
>   from the TEXT value and the remainder ignored. Any leading spaces in
>   the TEXT value when converting from TEXT to INTEGER are ignored.
>
> If there is no prefix that can be interpreted as an integer number,
>   the result of the conversion is 0.
>
> If the prefix integer is greater than +9223372036854775807 then the
>   result of the cast is exactly +9223372036854775807. 
>   Similarly, if the
>   prefix integer is less than -9223372036854775808 then the result of
>   the cast is exactly -9223372036854775808.
>
> When casting to INTEGER, if the text looks like a floating point value with an exponent, the exponent will be ignored because it is no
>   part of the integer prefix. For example, "(CAST '123e+5' AS INTEGER)"
>   results in 123, not in 12300000.
>
> The CAST operator understands decimal integers only — conversion of hexadecimal integers stops at the "x" in the "0x" prefix of the
>   hexadecimal integer string and thus result of the CAST is always zero.
>
> A cast of a REAL value into an INTEGER results in the integer between the REAL value and zero that is closest to the REAL value. If
>   a REAL is greater than the greatest possible signed integer
>   (+9223372036854775807) then the result is the greatest possible signed
>   integer and if the REAL is less than the least possible signed integer
>   (-9223372036854775808) then the result is the least possible signed
>   integer.
>
> Prior to SQLite version 3.8.2 (2013-12-06), casting a REAL value greater than +9223372036854775807.0 into an integer resulted in the
>   most negative integer, -9223372036854775808. This behavior was meant
>   to emulate the behavior of x86/x64 hardware when doing the equivalent
>   cast.
>
> #### NUMERIC
>
> Casting a TEXT or BLOB value into NUMERIC first does a forced conversion into REAL but then further converts the result into
>   INTEGER if and only if the conversion from REAL to INTEGER is lossless
>   and reversible. **This is the only context in SQLite where the NUMERIC
>   and INTEGER affinities behave differently**.
>
> Casting a REAL or INTEGER value to NUMERIC is a no-op, even if a real
>   value could be losslessly converted to an integer.

### NOTE

Before this section there is a section on **Literal Values** (i.e. casting probably only needs to be applied to values extracted from columns).

Try :-

```
SELECT
    round(CAST(10 AS NUMERIC) + CAST(254.53 AS NUMERIC),2) = round(CAST(264.53 AS NUMERIC),2) AS TestComparison1,

    round(CAST(10 AS NUMERIC) + CAST(254.54 AS NUMERIC),2) = round(CAST(264.54 AS NUMERIC),2) AS TestComparison2
```

:-
[image]

Comment: yup - expand your answer to explain why and how this fits / doesn't fit with the documentation and I'll mark it as the accepted.

Personally, my reading of the documentation means this is a bug or just bad documentation. Or, my lack of reading comprehension. I'm not sure which! :)

I'm more of a SQL Server guy and MSSQL uses a much stricter / predicable set of affinity rules.

Comment: Thank you! Nice job! That last sentence / copy from the documentation is key to understanding SQLite's behavior in this case.